# I cant connect my PlayStation account to my Mojang account, why?

Tags: ps4, minecraft-legacy-console

Why am I unable to connect my PlayStation account to my Mojang account? I tried looking for solutions from YouTube videos and from the Mojang website.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Did you receive any error messages? When you attempt to connect, what happened?

Comment: I wasn't even aware that you could link them. When you say link what are you trying to achieve? Did you pay for minecraft on PC and are now trying to play on your Playstation?

Answer (score 0):

### You cannot "link" Mojang and PSN

This can be done only on platforms that run the Windows 10 version of Minecraft

> Minecraft for Windows 10 is an edition of Minecraft designed for Windows 10, featuring cross-play with players on Xbox One, iOS and Android phones, Nintendo Switch, and more.

<sup>[Source](https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2064007-minecraft-for-windows-10)</sup>

Unfortunately, the PlayStation version is not on this list. It is running a different version of Minecraft, which does not have the capability to "link" to your Mojang Account.

> This edition is the only version of Legacy Console Edition that still receives major updates. It matched the now discontinued Xbox One Edition in available content, such as large size and amplified world options.

<sup>[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/PlayStation_4_Edition)</sup>

Comment: This is not even true, no version can be linked to a Mojang account (though old Minecraft accounts can be migrated to email-based Mojang accounts, **only** for Java Edition). The only account you can link Bedrock platforms to is the Xbox account (which is also usually linked to a Microsoft account).

Comment: @Manchineel the point of the answer is to answer the question - PS does not allow for cross-console play. Others do, and the use of inverted commas around "linked" is a word used to label this capability.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. The answer in on itself is correct, I was just pointing out that not even "This can be done only on platforms that run the Windows 10 version of Minecraft" is true, since the account they can sync with is not a Mojang account, but an Xbox one. But I guess I'm being pedantic.